# Is there a name for the reflections used on Apple demo images?

Tags: terminology, image

If you look at the advertising image of any Apple product (just go on the apple homepage) you'll see that they all have the screen reflecting light in such a way that half the reflection is dark, the other half is light, and they are separated very sharply. Is there a word for this technique? I've been seeing it everywhere these days.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually called "**gloss**" as the intention is for it to make the image look more glossy.  A similar thing is used on iOS icons.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple's checkout process](http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MD103LL/A):

> Display
>
> The 15-inch MacBook Pro comes with a 1,440-by-900-pixel LED-backlit, glossy display. You can also choose a high-resolution,
>   1,680-by-1,050 glossy or anti-glare display that gives you 36 percent
>   more pixels.

It can be called either **gloss** or **glare** because a screen that has this effect is glossy and a screen that doesn't have this effect is anti-glare.

Comment: I think OP is talking about the way they show the image, with the dark and light halves of the screen, not what the actual screen is called.

Comment: ...but from a nomenclature perspective those two are one and the same. No?

Comment: @DrFriedParts No they aren't.  One is talking about a visual effect, and the other is talking about a property of the hardware.  I just so happens that in this case they use similar words, but the meaning is different.

Answer (score 1):

"[screen glare effect](https://www.google.com/search?q=photoshop%20screen%20glare&oq=photoshop%20screen%20glare&aqs=chrome.0.57j62.4594j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=screen%20glare%20effect&oq=screen%20glare%20effect&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i8i30l2.72757.72757.3.73018.1.1.0.0.0.0.101.101.0j1.1.0...0.0.0..1c.1.15.psy-ab.NpmkmtRZPH0&pbx=1&pws=0&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.cGE&fp=779a49d6fdd15bbe&biw=1220&bih=701)" is the common term I think.  A popular Photoshop technique for device product images.